# Fundamental group of surface of genus $g$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Suppose we have a compact surface of genus $g$.

How to calculate its fundamental group ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look it up in a standard book on algebraic topology (see [Lee](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441979395), or see [Massey](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387902716)). The standard way this is done is by using regular polygons. You can represent your compact surface as a certain quotient space by the edges of a polygon. Once you have that representation the rest gets easier. Massey does it in Chapter 1.

Answer (score 6):

If the surface is *orientable*, then we have the [formula](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2013/REUPapers/Actipes.pdf) :

$$\pi_1(S)=\langle\;a_1,b_1,...,a_g,b_g\;:\;\;[a_1,b_1]\cdot\ldots\cdot [a_g,b_g]=1\;\rangle$$

(check theorem 6.3. in the above paper)